# Help solving a digit and word code problem/riddle: sum of four "ONE"s is "TEN"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem, cryptarithm

> Replace each letter by a digit. The same digit must represent each
> letter, and no beginning letter of a word can be zero. No two letters can
> be the same number. Find the digits represented by the letters 'O',
> 'N', 'E', 'T'.
>
> O N E
>
> O N E
>
> O N E
>
> O N E
>
> =====
>
> T E N

I have tried this, but I can't seem to crack it. It doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you want the solution or the explanation. Like I have that $E=2, N=8, O=1$ and $T=7$ but I can't really explain it.

Comment: i have the solution, I need the explanation?? Please explain

Comment: The key point is the last two digits.  We have two digits, $N,E$ such that $4\times (10N+E)\equiv 10E+N\pmod {100}$ which simplifies to $39N\equiv 6E\pmod {100}$.  Easy to find $N,E$ given that.

Comment: where did you get 10N from ?

Comment: Well,  ONE means $100\times O + 10\times N + E$, yes?

Comment: No, am actually very confused.

Comment: Well, perhaps you'd do better with a brute search then.  Again, just focus on the $N,E$ for now.  Check every number from $0$ to $99$ to find the one such that multiplying by $4$ reverses the last two digits.  My method avoids that brute search, but there's still a search involved (and perhaps I'm using vocabulary you don't know).

Comment: You can shorten  the search by noting that $4\times ONE $ is obviously even, hence $N$ must be one of $0,2,4,6,8$.

Comment: I do understand your language, however I don't understand this is part were you say find two digits that multiply by 4  is reversed?

Comment: Take a look at http://cryptarithms.awardspace.us/150-puzzles-in-crypt-arithmetic.pdf ; you will find a lot of these, for example (pages 37-38) TWO+THREE+SEVEN=TWELVE, NINE - FOUR = FIVE, FORTY+TEN+TEN=SIXTY, etc.

Comment: Thank you this helped sooo much, I got the answer now

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different method:  EN has to be a multiple of 4 and EN+NE is a multiple of 5 (last two digits match 5×NE), therefore E+N is a multiple of 5.  For any choice of E we can pick N forcing the sum to be a multiple of 5 and N to be even, leaving only one possible N for each E.  The only such candidates for EN that are also multiples of 4:  00, 28, 32, 64, 96.  Of these only EN=00 and EN=28 are consistent with NE×4 ending with EN.  Then 00 violates the usual rule that different letters represent different digits and is just plain inelegant (100+...+100=400?  Come on!).  So E=2 and N=8.  We then can't begin ONE with 0 (convention) or greater than 1 (ONE<1000/4=250), so 182+...+182=728 is all there is.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $E$ and $N$ represent different digits, we need $E\ne0$.

$$400O+40N+4E=100T+10E+N$$
Therefore
$$
400O+39N=100T+6E
$$
If we reduce modulo $100$, we see that $39N\equiv 6E\pmod{100}$, so $13N\equiv 2E\pmod{100}$. Since the inverse of $13$ modulo $100$ is $77$, we have $N\equiv77\cdot2E\equiv54E\pmod{100}$.

Compute $54x$ modulo $100$ for $1\le x\le9$ to see when the remainder is between $0$ and $9$.

> It's only possible for $x=2$. Thus $E=2$ and $N=8$. Then $400O+312=100T+12$, $O=1$ and $T=7$.

Comment: $O=0$ is not possible as the " no beginning letter of a word can be zero."

Comment: I got rid of it.

Comment: You know, you don't actually need the spoiler. I spoiled it in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

'ONE' represents the number $100 \times O + 10 \times N + E$, just as $781$ represents $7 \times 100 + 8 \times 10 + 1$. This is what the decimal position
system **is**.

So 'ONE' added 4 times to itself is just $400 \times O + 40 \times N + 4E$ and this should represent the same number as 'TEN' = $100 \times T + 10\times E + N$.

This means 'N' is a the final digit of a multiple of $4$, so $2,4,6,8,0$ are the options for 'N'. For more hints, see the comments.